# Creating distinct Checkboxes in a For Loop that can be referenced separately

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm creating a show tracker, and on the actual tracker page I want to load a scrolling ScrolledText box with a checkbox for each episode retrieved (I have chosen a ScrolledText box as it allows me to scroll if the amount of episodes fills over the screen). The code below does this perfectly, however each checkbox is referred to as the same variable, and thus every time I click one episode number, it selects all of them.

```py
for alignment in range(1,int(showDisplay_episodesAmount)+1):
            # create a radio button
            self.showDisplay.episodeCheckbox = Checkbutton(self.showDisplay.episodesScrollBox, text=alignment,variable=var1, onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
            self.showDisplay.episodeCheckbox.grid(column=0, row=grid_column)
            self.showDisplay.episodesScrollBox.window_create('end', window=self.showDisplay.episodeCheckbox)
            self.showDisplay.episodesScrollBox.insert('end', '\n')
            grid_column += 1
```

I would like each checkbox to correspond to a separate episode number (such as checkbox 1 referring to episode 1, etc.), created in a for loop, as I cannot predetermine the amount of episodes for a wide variety of shows.I have tried the list approach, making this code, which both doesn't create separate checkboxes, and disables the scrollbar:

```py
for alignment in range(1,int(showDisplay_episodesAmount)+1):
            # create a radio button
            self.showDisplay.episodeCheckbox[alignment] = {}
            self.showDisplay.episodeCheckbox[alignment]['name'] = alignment
            self.showDisplay.episodeCheckbox[alignment]['checkbox'] = Checkbutton(self.showDisplay.episodesScrollBox, text=alignment,variable=var1, onvalue=1, offvalue=0).grid(column=0, row=grid_column)
            #self.showDisplay.episodesScrollBox.window_create('end', window=self.showDisplay.episodeCheckbox[alignment])
            self.showDisplay.episodesScrollBox.insert('end', '\n')
            grid_column += 1
```

How could I make each checkbox generated distinct and not linked to each other?

Comment: You need to use different `IntVar` for each checkbutton.

Comment: Tried with both examples, did not work for either!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the simple version of Jhonatan but you can also do something more sophisticated like creating a dictionary in which the key is the progressive counter of episode (your alignment) and the value is the checkboxed itself, from which you can access the state.
I don't use plain tk checkboxes but rather ttk, so here it's an example with ttk:

```
from tkinter import ttk
checkboxes_dictionary={}
for alignment in range(1,int(showDisplay_episodesAmount)+1):
    checkboxes_dictionary[alignment]=ttk.Checkbutton(self.showDisplay.episodesScrollBox, text=alignment)
    checkboxes_dictionary[alignment].pack()
```

Here I'm assuming you are interested in only showing the state of the checkboxes so I omitted the var.

You can access the state of your checkboxes with this line:

```
checkboxes_dictionary[my_episode].state()
```

Where of course my_episode is an integer between 0 and showDisplay_episodesAmount. You can also sweep this dictionary to print the status of all the episodes (checked / unchecked).

Final note, in ttk the return of the state() method is not binary, rather is a string that has many values ("selected", "focus" and many others, and two or more of them can coexist so the output will be a list of these string. Look at the [documentation](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/ttk-map.html)

I haven't check my code so please review it

Comment: Hi there, thank you for your answer! I've taken a look at it and attempted to implement this into my code. I got this code to work:


for alignment in range(1,int(showDisplay_episodesAmount)+1):
            self.showDisplay.checkboxes_dictionary[alignment]=ttk.Checkbutton(self.showDisplay.episodesScrollBox, text=alignment)
            self.showDisplay.checkboxes_dictionary[alignment].grid(column=0, row=grid_column)

However with this code only one checkbox is placed in the ScrollBox, being a checkbox showing the last episode. What have I done wrong?

Comment: not sure since I'm just using basic function of GUI and in particular ttk. Probabily somehow you are overwriting the checkboxed with the grid placement: they may be still there, but are on top of each other so you see only the last one. To check this hypothesis you can deo two things: use pack() as in my example for automatic placement; iterate over the dictionary and print the state. In the latter, even if you don't see the checkboxed and cannot select them, status will be printed. Or just use the debugger and ispect the dictionary content.

Comment: Ah, it seems that using .pack() was the right move here (I've been using Grid as I like precise positioning)! I even managed to get the scrollbar to work with this approach by messing around with .pack() arguments. Thank you for your help :>

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use a list instead of the variable.
Then you can set each episode to one item in the list. like this:

```
listofvar = []
for alignment in range(1,int(showDisplay_episodesAmount)+1):
        listosvar.append(tk.StringVar())
        # create a radio button
        self.showDisplay.episodeCheckbox = Checkbutton(self.showDisplay.episodesScrollBox, text=alignment,variable=listofvar[alignment-1], onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
        self.showDisplay.episodeCheckbox.grid(column=0, row=grid_column)
        self.showDisplay.episodesScrollBox.window_create('end', window=self.showDisplay.episodeCheckbox)
        self.showDisplay.episodesScrollBox.insert('end', '\n')
        grid_column += 1
```

Now each checkbox will define one item in the list ...

Hope I helped.

Jonathan

Comment: Hi there, thank you for your answer! Just a question, how would I get input from a specific checkbox? The list 'listofvar' creates a list of variables, but how do I utilise them?